# C3 graph: gridlines misaligned from ticks by consistent amount

Tags: c3.js

I've got a strange issue with my C3 graph. This is a Rails app: I'm using the `c3-rails` gem and `d3-rails` 3.5.17 gem.

As you can see in the screenshot below, I'm finding that my gridlines are offset from the ticks, each by the same amount. Each gridline is left-shifted by an amount equal to that of the extra space at the right of the x-axis.

[image: Graph with misaligned gridlines]

Here's the code:

```
const chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: "#graph",
 data: {
   x: 'x',
   columns: [
     myData.dateTime, myData.values
   ]
 },
 legend: {
   hide: true
 },
 grid: {
   x: {
     show: true
   },
   focus: {
     show: true
   }
 },
 axis: {
   x: {
     localtime: true,
     type: 'timeseries',
     tick: {
       count: 9,
       format: '%d %b, %H:%M',
       rotate: 50
     },
     padding: {
       left: 0,
       right: 0
     }
   },
   y: {
     label: {
       text: json.y_title,
       position: 'outer-middle'
     }
   }
 }
})
```

Per the [C3 docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html#grid-x-show), it seems like it's not possible to customise the basic gridline functionality, although you can add [extra gridlines](http://c3js.org/reference.html#grid-x-lines). However, I can't use that approach since my data is dynamic.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check .c3-xgrids and .c3-xgrid for unwanted styles?

Comment: Yes - I can't see anything amiss. The x values are off, of course, but if I hardcode the difference then obviously the graph won't scale.